# C# Send argument through Process.Exited

Tags: c#

I start a process that uses `process.exited` to send the program instructions on what to do with the process is finished.

It works fine, But I need to send a argument to the `Process_Exited()` method. Something like this:

```
process.exited += Process_Exited(jobnumber);
```

But that does not work. Here is my code:

```
public void x264_thread(string jobnumber, string x264_argument, string audio_argument)
{
    file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\output\\current.out");
    mysqlconnect("UPDATE h264_encoder set status = 'running' where jobnumber = '" + jobnumber + "'");
    var proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\ffmbc\\ffmbc.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = x264_argument;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
    proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
    proc.Exited += process_Exited(JobNumber); //This is where I would like to include a argument

    proc.Start();
    proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
}
```

Then it goes to the `process_Exited` Method:

```
public void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e, string JobNumber) //This does not work. It does not pass the string JobNumber
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

I would like to send the `process_Exited()` method an argument from the x264_thread

Comment: It's `process` - one `c`, two `s` ..

Answer (score 10):

Just use a lambda:

```
proc.Exited += (sender, e) => process_Exited(sender, e, JobNumber);
```

The compiler now generates lots of IL, a hidden class and a hidden method to make it all work.

Lambdas are great for adapting signatures and passing additional state.

Comment: All the extra weight from the lambda capture is not needed. And it is a hot spot for deadlock pitfalls because now the process object is holding a reference to who knows what. You already have the process object, just index the jobs by pid.

Comment: @TamirDaniely starting a process is 100000x more expensive than these allocations. It's not important to optimize this. If by deadlock you refer to the possibility that the lambda might keep other local values alive then that's always a possibility in many scenarios using closures. But why are you pointing out that risk here specifically? Is this a high risk scenario in your mind?

Comment: In every company I worked ever definitely yes. If I leave code that can be deadlocked, someone will come in and create a deadlock. In fact it's my number 1 thing to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

You can not change the signature of an event handler like `Process.Exited` but in your event handler code, you can cast `sender` as type `Process` since `sender` is really the instance of your original process.  Now that you know the process, you could determine your JobNumber:

```
public void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Process myProcess = (Process)sender;
    // use myProcess to determine which job number....
    // DoWork
}
```

Now, to get which job number is associated with which process, you could do this:

Put a field in your class:

```
private Dictionary<Process, string> _processDictionary = 
                               new Dictionary<Process,string>();
```

In your `x264_thread` method you could add an entry after you create the process:

```
_processDictionary.Add(proc, jobnumber);
```

Then in your event handler you could retrieve the value:

```
public void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Process myProcess = (Process)sender;
    // use myProcess to determine which job number....
    var jobNumber = _processDictionary[myProcess];
    _processDictionary.Remove(myProcess);
    // DoWork
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better (less expensive) to use process Id as the key to the dictionary?